# MoviePy Error: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, ffmpeg, windows-10, moviepy

I'm getting the error in the title when trying to run the example code below on Windows 10/Python 3.6.1/Sublime Text Editor 3. I made sure to set my `MAGICK_HOME` environment variable to point to where I manually installed ImageMagick. I made sure to only have 1 version of ImageMagick installed. I made sure FFMPEG, Numpy, imageio, Decorator, and tqdm were all installed.

Yes, the file "vidclip.mp4" exists. The desired behavior here is to simply clip the video and add text to the center as per the example on the github page, i.e. to simply run the code successfully.

Does anyone know what might be wrong?

**Example code from [github](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy#example):**

```
from moviepy.editor import *

video = VideoFileClip("vidclip.mp4").subclip(7,64)

# Make the text. Many more options are available.
txt_clip = ( TextClip("Ken Block who?",fontsize=70,color='white')
             .set_position('center')
             .set_duration(10) )

result = CompositeVideoClip([video, txt_clip]) # Overlay text on video
result.write_videofile("vidclip_edited.webm",fps=25) # Many options...
```

**The full error trace:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\av\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\VideoClip.py", line 1220, in __init__
    subprocess_call(cmd, verbose=False )
  File "C:\Users\av\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\moviepy\tools.py", line 42, in subprocess_call
    proc = sp.Popen(cmd, **popen_params)
  File "C:\Users\av\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\av\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\av\Desktop\Desktop\Projects\Youtube\blender\test\testMoviePy.py", line 6, in <module>
    txt_clip = ( TextClip("Ken Block who?",fontsize=70,color='white')
  File "C:\Users\av\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\VideoClip.py", line 1229, in __init__
    raise IOError(error)
OSError: MoviePy Error: creation of None failed because of the following error:

[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified.

.This error can be due to the fact that ImageMagick is not installed on your computer, or (for Windows users) that you didn't specify the path to the ImageMagick binary in file conf.py, or.that the path you specified is incorrect
```

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? I'd be happy to fix the question.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. I didn't realize it was ***imperative*** that I specify the location of `ffmpeg.exe` and `convert.exe` within ImageMagick's `config_defaults.py` file. After that, I install MoviePy (in that order).